# The effect of selecting the target compilation platform on the execution mode of a managed application in Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio

If I specify in Visual Studio the target compilation platform as ARM or Itanium, what format will the resulting executable file have: PE32 or PE32+?

Also interested in this question: When specifying the target platform as `anycpu32bit-preferred`, in which mode (like x64 application, x86 application, WOW64) the executable file will be executed on Windows RT (ARM) and on Windows IA64?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense, you can't specifically target ARM or Itanium in a .NET project.  Only two options in the Project > Properties > Build tab.  Platform target selects PE32+ if you pick x64, PE32 for x86 and AnyCPU.  The Prefer 32-bit checkbox was added in 4.5 and was meant to handle an ambiguity when 64-bit ARM cores became available.  Necessary because x86 could mean 32-bit or could mean that only an x86 core is supported.  Do keep in mind that Itanium and Windows RT are completely dead.

Comment: My question arose from the reading of Richter's book. There was raised this topic and some information was given, as I think, is not true. How with the compilation under Itanium we get the PE32+/ARM module? And threre are different infromation in different publications.

Comment: if you claim that this information is useless, I will believe you and will not wonder.